# I want to save some code in tool box using visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I usually use two solution which is for window form and WCF with visual studio 2013 at the same time. I am tried to save some code which frequently used in Tool box. but I add some code in WCF solution and in Win form solution as well at the same time. It didn’t save all of what I want to save. how can i save both of them? sometimes, toolbox is reset so I would like to back up code which I add to tool box. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

For these tasks I create Visual Studio snippets. To comfortably create and edit snippets I use a Visual Studio plugin called Snippet Designer. So I just have to type a "shortcode" which I assigned to the snippet and press TAB. Works like the builtin snippets for, foreach etc.

[MSDN Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx)
[Snippetdesigner at codeplex](http://snippetdesigner.codeplex.com/)